# How do you compare each value you call from a method?

Tags: java, string, file, methods

Ask the user to give you the name of a file containing a series of words, one-per-line, and compute the score of every word in the file. Report back to the user which word was the most positive and which was the most negative. An example run might look like this:

for a file that looks like:

```
terrible
horrible
ok
refreshing
formulaic
```

---

This basically what I have to do...
The code I'm writing for this question is

---

```
    // Scanner input for user to put in values
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // File
    File file = new File("MovieReviews.txt");
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file);

    // User input of file
    System.out.println(" Enter the name of the file with words you want to score : ");
    String fileName = input.nextLine();
    File file2 = new File(fileName);
    Scanner fileInput2 = new Scanner(file2);

    // Loop
    while (fileInput2.hasNext()) {
        String word = fileInput2.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        double scores = (double) rating(fileInput, word);

    }

}
// Method

public static double rating(Scanner fileInput, String word) {
    // Variables
    double score = 0;
    double rate = 0;
    int count = 0;

    // Loop
    while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
        int rating = fileInput.nextInt();
        String review = fileInput.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        int location = review.indexOf(word);

        if (location >= 0) {

            count++;
            rate = rate + rating;
            score = rate / count;

        }
    }
    return score;
}

}
```

---

Please help me out here..
I don't know how to compare the values and get the biggest/smallest.

Comment: JavaScript != Java.

Comment: How do you "compute the score of a word"?  How is any one word "more positive" than another?  If you're asking to write a program which assigns intuitive weights to words based on human language, it's going to take *a lot* more code.

Comment: Plz specify what do you mean by "score of a word"?

Comment: If you are looking to measure the emotion of the words, it is bit more complicated. You can start from this [research](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225045375_Emotion_Detection_from_Text) .

Comment: basically I have a file that contains all sorts of reviews for a movie that also contains the rating of that movie too called 'movie review'. I want the user to input a file which contains some random words and see how many times each word comes out on the 'movie review file' and the total of the ratings and calculate them to get the average rating of each word and compare each rating value to get the highest and lowest. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question and going through your code a few times, I think this is what your objective is:

You have a file 1 in the following format:

```
abc 5.6
pqrs 3.2
xyz 9.3
abc 7.9
lmnop 5.2
```

Your program asks user to enter a file 2 location (different from the above file) which has just content of words (movies).

```
abc
xyz
sdf
```

Then your program is supposed to read each of the words (movies) from file 2 and find their reviews from  file 1 and take average. Finally, your program has to return the movie with the highest review and the movie with the lowest review (e.g. in the above case xyz has the highest average review and abc has the lowest average review. (The movie sdf doesn't have any review in file 1 so it will be disregarded).

**Solution**

You can use a `Map` to store word (movie name) as the key and average rating as value. So in other words, you can use a data structure like `Map<String, Double>`. Then, all you have to do is sort the collection and return the first and the last items. See the following code snippet which is modified from yours:

```
Map<String, Double> map= new HashMap<>();
// Loop
while (fileInput2.hasNext()) {
    String word = fileInput2.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    double scores = (double) rating(fileInput, word);
    map.put(word, scores);
}

Collections.sort(map, new Comparator<Entry<String, Double>>()
  {
     public int compare(Entry<String, Double>> o1, Entry<String, Double>> o2) {
         return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
     }
  });
```